# Form_tag 'create' vs '/create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm exploring all options for form_tag and I noticed that if I use `form_tag(action:'create')` it would do post 'create'.

However, if I use `form_tag('/create')` or `form_tag('create')` I get this error in browser\

```
No route matches [POST] "/create"
```

I merely extrapolate from the example given in the Rails documentation on form_tag to use '/create' (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag).

**Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?**

Answer (score 1):

`form_tag` needs whatever is necessary to find a path for sending data.

`action: 'create'`, which is resolved to `{action: 'create'}`, a `Hash`, invokes a routing system (with rules defined in `routes.rb`) to find a route in the same controller (the current view is in) for `create` action.

Otherwise, it's more commonly used with path helpers, returning paths as strings. When you specify a string manually, it's used as a path directly. Most of the time this is **not what you want**. All path helpers can be found by invoking `rake routes`. For a bare-bones app I threw together for a test this is what I get:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern Controller#Action
  root GET  /           application#index
```

This means that you have methods `root_path` and `root_url` (`Prefix` hints) that routes path '/' into `ApplicationController`, action `index`. If I had something accepting a POST on the same path (the table above says I don't), I would have written this:

```
form_tag(root_path) # parentheses are optional, it's Ruby!
```

PS: routing anything to `ApplicationController` is bad practice. So yes, it's an impractical example, which nevertheless explains what's this all about.